# How to set default duration for new Calender events

Tags: terminal, mojave, calendar

When creating new calendar events in the Calendar application the duration of the event defaults to 60 min. In earlier version of macOS it apparently was possible to change this by running

```
defaults write com.apple.iCal 'Default duration in minutes for new event' 120
```

but it doesn't seem to work anymore with Mojave (it does set the new value but Calender still creates events with 60 minutes after restarting). So how can I change the default duration for new events in Mojave?

Comment: Can you please help us in understanding the problem a bit more in detail? You talk about the default time for events, the default duration, and missing notifications (and maybe more), so it's not really clear what the issue is and which problem you are trying to solve. It also might help to explain where the data dumped at the end of the question text comes from, and how it relates to the question. If you think the answer to your question is somewhere in there, it might be enough to just post the command which generates it (so that people can reproduce the result with their own Mac).

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment, this is my first post and I'm afraid is shows. 1. The problem for me is that I don't know the specific command (if any) to give terminal that would establish a different default time for a Calendar New Event entry.  It currently defaults to 9am to 10am.  I would like a longer time, maybe 12 hours or all day.

Comment: I did a rather heavy edit and removed all the things which don't directly add details to the question as such. If I missed something essential please edit it back it.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping.  This is obviously my first post, but I use your site repeatedly for help.